# Change the way theorems are numbered within a document

Tags: numbering, theorems

I'm working a document that has one (very large) chapter, in which theorems, lemmas, etc. are numbered with `subsubsection`, i.e. the start of the document has the command

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsubsection]{Theorem}
```

However, the document also has some short chapters, in which theorems etc. are numbered with `subsection`. At the moment, the only way I can do this is to also define a `theorem_` at the beginning of the document:

```
\newtheorem{theorem_}[subsection]{Theorem}
```

and use `theorem` sometimes and `theorem_` other times. This seems like an ugly hack, and I'd love it if there were some way I could use `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` throughout the document, and use some command at the start of each chapter to determine whether theorems were numbered with `subsection` or `subsubsection`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}
```

immediately before the chapter you wish you change.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsubsection]

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\subsubsection{subsubsec}
\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}
\chapter{two}
\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\subsubsection{subsubsec}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:test}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\ref{thm:test}

\end{document}
```

Changing the numbering convention part way through a document could cause confusion to your reader. How many theorems do you have? Does the numbering need to go so deep? Just some thoughts :)

Comment: Otherwise you can use `\counterwithin{theorem}{subsection}` from the package `chngcntr`.

Comment: I'm well aware that changing the numbering convention could cause confusion - the problem is, I don't have control over the numbering. And the document is ~150 pages, so yes, the numbering does need to that deep. Thanks for this nice solution though!

Comment: In the OP's intention, `theorem` shares the `subsubsection` counter, it's not subordinate to it. So there's no `\thetheorem`

Comment: @egreg thanks for pointing that out. in which case karlkoeller's idea seems more appropriate