# Numbering theorems in a chapter with no sections

Tags: numbering, theorems

Say I have an index such as:

```
1. Chapter
  1.1 Section
  1.2 Section
2. Chapter
3. Chapter
```

and I number my theorems as

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

with the last theorem in 1.2 being Theorem 1.2.5. Then the first theorem in chapter two will be 2.0.6.

My first question is: is this really a feature and not a bug? Is there a situation where this is the preferred behavior?

My second question is about how to fix it. I would like the theorems in Chapter 2 to be 2.1, 2.2, etc while keeping the theorems in Chapter 1 to appear as 1.1.1, 1.1.2, etc. I can manually do it various ways ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/change-the-way-theorems-are-numbered-within-a-document)) by putting in code in individual chapters. But I shouldn't have to do such a thing, should I? I would really like to have a solution where the format of the numbering is determined entirely in the preamble.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
 \begin{chapter}{Chapter 1}
  \begin{section}{Secton 1.1}
   \begin{theorem}
    asdf
   \end{theorem}
   \begin{theorem}
    asdf
   \end{theorem}
  \end{section}
 \end{chapter}
 \begin{chapter}{Chapter 2}
  \begin{theorem}
   asdf
  \end{theorem}
 \end{chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This the default behaviour (which answers the second question). The preferred behaviour most likely depends on the document. In your case, I would use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]` rather (answering the first).

Comment: @Werner: Well shoot, I completely misunderstood the meaning of the optional parameter [chapter] (or [section]). Thanks. This is a bad question.

Comment: @Werner: Whoops, spoke too soon. I still want numbers such as 1.2.1 when there is a section within a chapter. Your recommendation does not have this.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: I know. My suggestion is to stick to something that works across all of your chapters (with/without sections). And that is to use `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`. It would also be consistent. It would be possible to devise a numbering that works in both instances, but that would not be consistent in terms of its representation.

Comment: See [Is it a bad idea to use `\begin{section}` … `\end{section}` in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12001/5764)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following conditions on the value of `section`, inserting it into the theorem numbering as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}% Reset theorem counter with every section
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}% Reset theorem counter with every chapter

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 
    \thechapter% "no section"
  \else
    \thesection% at least within a section
  \fi%
  .\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
asdf. See Theorem~\ref{abc} and~\ref{def}.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{abc}
asdf
\end{theorem}
\section{Second section}
\begin{theorem}
asdf
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
asdf
\end{theorem}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{theorem}\label{def}
asdf
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Note that you have to consider that `theorem` counters are reset with every `\chapter` *and* `\section`, otherwise you'd have `Theorem 2.3` starting off in Chapter 2 in the above example. Also, if you have a theorem inside the "introductory" part of a chapter that eventually will contain a section, then you'll still receive the "reduced" numbering.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little 'programing' helps to maintain section countering for theorems when there is a section and to drop it, when there is no section!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}%
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}%
\makeatother

\let\OriginalTheTheorem\thetheorem
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{section}}{0}{\thechapter.\arabic{theorem}}{%
\OriginalTheTheorem}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{chapter}{Chapter 1}
  \begin{section}{Secton 1.1}
   \begin{theorem}
    asdf
   \end{theorem}
   \begin{theorem}
    asdf
   \end{theorem}
  \end{section}
 \end{chapter}
 \begin{chapter}{Chapter 2}
  \begin{theorem}
   asdf
  \end{theorem}
 \end{chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does help, but unfortunately the first theorem of chapter 2 is 2.3 and not 2.1.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Yes, I forgot that condition, I working out another solution.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: I used a similar style compared to Werners solution, using the direct `\@addtoreset` way.